# mysql bigint(250) overkill or not / max field size

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to increase database performance of one of my customers.
many tables have bigint(250). I've read on MySql documentation that the bigint is max 8 bits/bytes. I don't understand why it is possible to have a bigint(250) while the max is 8?

Also with the INT fields, some fields have INT(25), but INT is max 8 bit/bytes.

Do I see this correct or not?

And what does MySql with sizes that are bigger than the field size?

Comment: I believe that the size fields in MySql relate to the number of decimal digits, rather than anything that would make logical sense to a programmer.

Comment: The number in column is for display size. If you had INT(1), it'd still be 4 bytes, but you'd only see 1 digit displayed even though internally all 4 bytes would be used. Apparently, someone designed your database without actually knowing what numbers in brackets are. It can't hurt to have such big numbers, but you can freely omit them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When dealing with types such as INT, BIGINT, etc,, the numbers inside the parentheses are for display width only, unlike e.g. VARCHAR where it defines the storage size as well.

If the display width is this big, you can safely assume the designer just had a moment of insanity, because unless the width is less than the maximum value, it's basically useless.

It would be more important to determine whether the field is signed. Defining it as BIGINT UNSIGNED effectively doubles the range for fields that should never be negative, such as an identifier.

Comment: "you can safely assume the designer just has a moment of insanity" this made me chuckle